# Python heatmap: Change colour map and make asymmetrical

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

I want to build a heatmap of this data:

```
curation1       curation2       overlap
1      2      0
1      3      1098
1      4      11
1      5      137
1      6      105
1      7      338
2      3      351
2      4      0
2      5      1
2      6      0
2      7      0
3      4      132
3      5      215
3      6      91
3      7      191
4      5      6
4      6      10
4      7      19
5      6      37
5      7      95
6      7     146
```

I made a heatmap with this code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from matplotlib import colors

data_raw = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1],sep = '\t')
data_raw["curation1"] = pd.Categorical(data_raw["curation1"], data_raw.curation1.unique())
data_raw["curation2"] = pd.Categorical(data_raw["curation2"], data_raw.curation2.unique())
data_matrix = data_raw.pivot("curation1", "curation2", "overlap")

fig = plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(12,12))
heatplot = ax.imshow(data_matrix,cmap = 'BuPu')
#ax.set_xticklabels(data_matrix.columns)
#ax.set_yticklabels(data_matrix.index)
tick_spacing = 1
#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
#ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
ax.set_title("Overlap")
fig.savefig('output.pdf')
```

The output looks like this: [image: this]

I have three questions:

1. You can see the color scheme is a bit 'off' in the sense that most of the data is very lightly colored, and there is a random purple box to indicate '0'. Ideally, I would like this heatmap being different shades of green, with the darkest green being the highest number, to the lightest (but still clearly visible) green being the lowest number. I tried to play around with the 'cmap' argument, e.g. changing it to 'winter' as described in the python tutorial [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar); but I'm doing something wrong. Could someone please tell me where specifically I could change this?
2. color bar: I would like to add a color bar, but I guess I need to sort out question 1 first.
3. asymmetrical: as you can see, this plot is asymmetrical. Is it possible to plot half of a heat map (e.g. get rid of the unnecessary lines and possibly moving the axis labels to the right hand side of the plot instead?; if not this isn't a big deal because I can re-jig it in powerpoint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your first two problems -

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(12,12))
heatplot = ax.imshow(data_matrix,cmap = 'Greens')

cbar = fig.colorbar(heatplot, ticks=[data_raw.overlap.min(), data_raw.overlap.max()])
tick_spacing = 1
ax.set_title("Overlap")
```

Comment: this is fantastic thank you, because the last part I can do in powerpoint. I'm annoyed at myself that I was so close with my cmap argument attempts! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `seaborn heatmap` function instead. The colormap `Greens` should do the trick with regards to your desired color scheme. If you'd like you can check out other options in the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

Just hihglight and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> the dataset in your question and run the snippet below:

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_raw = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
data_matrix = data_raw.pivot("curation1", "curation2", "overlap")
data_matrix = data_matrix.fillna(0)

# A heatmap function that builds on the seaborn heatmap function
def HeatMap_function(df, title, transpose = True, colors = 'Greens', dropDuplicates = True):

    if transpose:
        df = df.T
    
    if dropDuplicates:    
        mask = np.zeros_like(df, dtype=np.bool)
        mask = np.invert(mask)
        mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = False

    # Set background color / chart style
    sns.set_style(style = 'white')

    # Set up  matplotlib figure
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))
    ax.set_title(title)
  
    # Add diverging colormap from red to blue
    # cmap = sns.diverging_palette(250, 10, as_cmap=True)
    cmap=plt.get_cmap(colors)
    
    # Draw correlation plot with or without duplicates
    if dropDuplicates:
        sns.heatmap(df, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, 
                square=True,
                linewidth=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5}, ax=ax)
    else:
        sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap, 
                square=True,
                linewidth=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5}, ax=ax)

    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')

# A testrun
HeatMap_function(df = data_matrix, title = 'Overlap', transpose = False,
                 colors = 'Greens', dropDuplicates = True)
```

And you'll get this:

[image]

Now you can also change the layout of your plot by using different combinations of `transpose`, `colors` and `dropDuplicates`.

Comment: If this is something you think you can use, I'll edit in a few lines to store it in an active powerpoint presentation as well when I find the time.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with selecting a suiting colormap (have a look [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html)), for you purpose *Greens* might be good. Note that colormaps can be reversed by adding *'_r'* to the name.

Since your values differs quite a lot I would use logarithmic color scale.
You can do this by including `color.LogNorm` (from `import matplotlib.colors as colors`)

To address your third question I would move axis to top-right and remove bottom and left line.

```
# Plot heatmap
f, ax = plt.subplots()
lognorm = colors.LogNorm(vmin = data.min(), vmax = data.max())
heatplot  = ax.imshow(data, vmin = 1, norm = lognorm, cmap = 'Greens')

# Move axis to top-right and remove bottom and left line
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

# Use instead of ax.set_title to move title a bit higher up
f.suptitle('Overlap') 

# Add colorbar
cb = f.colorbar(heatplot)

f.show()
```

[image]